# Prevent PhpMailer from displaying messages

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have made  a successful contact form with phpmailer, however, whenever I display the thank you message , I always get this message.

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP e2sm28679155qaw.10 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [##.##.###.##] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.0 OK e2sm28679155qaw.10 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 OK e2sm28679155qaw.10 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Go ahead e2sm28679155qaw.10 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.0.0 OK 1416161162 e2sm28679155qaw.10 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:221 2.0.0 closing connection e2sm28679155qaw.10 - gsmtp
```

(##.##.###.##) is where my ip address is.

Can someone please help me get rid fo this message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove the following line from your `phpmailer` script.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
```

or

```
// 0 = off (for production use, No debug messages)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
```

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; //0 = off (for production use, No debug messages) debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

comment on this line for stop receiving messages or 
Prevent PhpMailer from displaying messages

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
```

from your phpmailer script.

```
//$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
```